# Pandas De-Duplicating without losing deleted data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have concat multiple data sources and each data source has it's own unique columns based on the data source. I want to merge rows who match on a list of columns and keep all unique data sources in the same row.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SharedData': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                    'df1Data': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SharedData': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                    'df2Data': ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8']})
```

```
newdf = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I need the resulting data set to go from before and after below.

Before Data Set:

| SharedData | df1Data | df2Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |
| B | 2 |  |
| C | 3 |  |
| D | 4 |  |
| E | 5 |  |
| D |  | 4 |
| E |  | 5 |
| F |  | 6 |
| G |  | 7 |
| H |  | 8 |

After Data Set:

| SharedData | df1Data | df2Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |
| B | 2 |  |
| C | 3 |  |
| D | 4 | 4 |
| E | 5 | 5 |
| F | 6 |  |
| G | 7 |  |
| H | 8 |  |

I need to deduplicate rows where SharedData matches, with a new row that contains all of the df specific data.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='SharedData', how='outer')`, then fillna on `df1Data` column with `df2Data` column.

Comment: Can 'on' be a list? My real data set has to match on 3 different columns

Comment: Yes, it can be a list `on=['col1','col2','col3']`.

Comment: last question. when I created each df I added a column named 'source' with df1 or df2. Is there a way to replace the source column with a list of both ['df1', 'df2']